# can i use include instead of session variables?

Tags: php

I am trying to pass the values of variables from one php page to another php page. Is it possible to include the previous php page in the next php page using `include` statement and use those variables and values rather than using `$_SESSION['variable']="value"`.

If not, is there any other way to pass the values? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use include but session usage is different from including page and use other page variables.

Comment: You have many way to store, you can write your data to a file, store to a DB... but session is the simplest way, why you don't want session ?

Comment: I am trying to create a script where a user can post something they want to sell and then I am using while loop in php to display the information from the database. Other users can click on the contact button and send an email to them. I was told that if I use 'session', the same email id will be stored for every listing. So I am wondering if I can use the hidden field and if so, how do I assign that php variable value to the html hidden field?

Answer (score 0):

No. You'll run the code in the included file again, from scratch. Any data produced based on user input will have been lost.

> If not, is there any other way to pass the values?

Passing the entire value to the browser and having it send the entire value back to the new script. (via form data, query strings in links, cookies, etc).

---

> I am trying to create a script where a user can post something they want to sell and then I am using while loop in php to display the information from the database. Other users can click on the contact button and send an email to them. I was told that if I use 'session', the same email id will be stored for every listing. So I am wondering if I can use the hidden field and if so, how do I assign that php variable value to the html hidden field?

You can't use hidden fields for this. You need to store *persistent* data on the server. Store the email address with the rest of the information in the database. (You'll probably want a separate user table and associate the For Sale item with a user using a foreign key).

Comment: oh okay thanks guys. On the other hand, if I am trying to do it for a form, can I create a html hidden field and pass it on to the other page? If so, how would I store the php variable value in to the hidden html field?

Comment: `value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($something_you_can_stringify); ?>"`